# Should [httpd] be a synonym for [apache-http-server]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

According to [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/248412/693277) "httpd" and "apache2" are basically the same in "big" OS-es.

> httpd is the same as apache2. It depends on the OS you use. For example in RHEL 6.2 it is called httpd and in Ubuntu it is called apache2.

The answer is from 2013 but it seems to me it's still valid.

[apache2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache2) is a synonym for [apache-http-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server); I think [httpd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/httpd) may be a synonym as well. I tried to suggest a synonym but I was denied due to my insufficient score in this tag.

On the other hand BusyBox HTTP Daemon [e.g. in OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/http.httpd) is also `httpd`; it's probably not related to Apache. This usage of "httpd" [seems](https://superuser.com/search?q=[httpd]+busybox) [marginal](https://superuser.com/search?q=[httpd]+openwrt) on Super User though.

Comparing to Unix & Linux SE: they have "apache-httpd" tag and relatively marginal "lighttpd", "openbsd-httpd" and "uhttpd" tags; no "httpd" tag at all.

Should [httpd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/httpd) be a synonym for [apache-http-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) on Super User?

---

[There are questions tagged "httpd" that do *not* mention Apache](https://superuser.com/search?q=[httpd]+-[apache-http-server]+is%3Aquestion+-apache). Most likely few of them will need to be retagged if we decide to synonymize the tags. I can review them, preferably before the synonym is approved. Should I also change all "valid" [httpd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/httpd) tags to [apache-http-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) then? or will they be remapped automatically when these tags get synonimized?

Comment: It sounds like even if they're the same, they're referred to differently in different environments.  Some readers scanning the main page looking for questions of interest wouldn't see the tag they're familiar with if they're synonyms.  It might reduce answers for one tag.  About 60% of the [httpd] questions are double-tagged with [apache-http-server], but that still leaves about 45 questions that aren't.  Might the community be best served by keeping the tags separate?  Just asking since this is out of my area.

Comment: I think a synonym could cause confusion based on the fact `httpd` can refer to Apache *and* the BusyBox daemon. Synonyms should reflect a 1:1 relationship between tags.

Comment: httpd is the superset of all http daemons, the apache http server software is one of those. the synonym is only on specific systems per an alias in the package manager or service configuration (defaults). users should be trained to do two searches and rate the results with the context of this basic information ordering to deal with potential (technically) wrong tagged content. don't solve communication issues w/ technical tools. just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No.

While true that some users may believe there is only one HTTP server, superuser should not add to the confusion. [httpd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/httpd) is a generic name for the daemon handling HTTP requests.

Before reading this question I would have assumed that someone using an unqualified [httpd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/httpd) meant the [http daemon in OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/httpd) which is simply named *httpd*.

It would be confusing if that tag actually *hides* questions about the daemon literally named `httpd` but showed questions about a specific server component of the Apache server.